# Delete element from array of objects

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm trying to get a handle on memory management in C++, so I've been writing a card game (which has a list of cards), but without using a `vector`.

Lets say I have an array of `Card`s like this: `Card** cards`.
Now, I want to replace a card, called `Card* remove`, with another card.

I believe that it is necessary for all of my `Card*`s in `cards` to be created with `new`, because other functions need to access them by pointer. Therefore, when I remove an element from `cards`, I should `delete` it as well.

However, when I call `delete remove`, it seems to mess with my array. Specifically, let's say `remove` happened to be at index 2. Obviously, before the `delete`, `cards[2] == remove`. However, after the `delete`, both `cards[2]` and `remove` have changed, whereas the pointer to `cards` is the same.

This might not be a bad thing, but I'm very confused as to why it's happening. Ideally, I would be able to delete the memory in the heap located at `remove` without modifying `cards` at all. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the exercise or assignment you're working on about pointers and dynamic memory allocation? Otherwise just use `std::vector<Card>`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's not an exercise/assignment, I'm trying to remind myself how memory allocation works in preparation for next quarter. Although I would normally just use a `vector`, this is mostly for learning purposes.

Comment: I am confused about what the problem is; what exactly is (or is not) changing that you don't (or do) think should change? Also, when you delete `remove` do you call `delete remove` or `delete cards[2]`?

Comment: One simple way to "remove" elements from an array of pointers is to not remove the element at all, and instead just set the pointer to be a null pointer (i.e. `cards[element_to_remove] = nullptr;`). Otherwise you could create a new array with one less element, and copy the remaining elements to the new array. Or you could just copy the higher elements down one step in the existing array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Wouldn't doing that cause a memory leak, because the object stored at `cards[element_to_remove]` would still exist in the heap?

Comment: @Frodyne I'm confused why calling `delete remove` changes the pointer at `cards[2]`. I'm currently calling `delete remove`. What would be the difference between calling `delete remove` and `delete cards[2]`?

Comment: @multitaskPro Well you need to `delete` is first of course. Every `new` should be matched by a `delete`.

Comment: I am wondering if you are running in debug mode, and the compiler has added instructions to write crap to any pointer that gets deleted, so that any access to that pointer from that point fails hard, instead of only failing after something else has randomly overwritten that bit of heap memory.

Comment: @Frodyne @Someprogrammerdude  Sorry to waste your time, I figured out the issue. The new card I want to insert is `Card insert`. Instead of doing `*cards[2] = insert`, I was doing `cards[2] = &insert`. Seems pretty obvious in retrospect :/ Thank you anyway!

Comment: well you should be using Vectors and learn memory management as done from C++ 11

Answer (score 1):

I've made a sample code that illustrates what you stated. But I did not observed what you said.
If you could show your code (minimal and reproducible example), we would be able to find what happened.

Deleting a pointer does not change the **pointer value** but releases the **pointed value**.

Here is the sample:

```
int main()
{
    typedef int Card;
    Card ** arr;

    // ---------- Init ----------
    arr = new Card* [5]; // five cards

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = new Card(static_cast<int>(i));
    }
    // --------------------------

    // Direct removal
    std::cout << arr[2] << ": " << *arr[2] << '\n';
    delete arr[2];
    std::cout << arr[2] << '\n'; // >>>>> The address did not change after the deletion
    arr[2] = nullptr;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Delegated removal
    Card * to_remove = arr[3];
    std::cout << to_remove << " / " << arr[3] << " : " << *arr[3] << '\n';
    delete to_remove;
    std::cout << to_remove << " / " << arr[3] << '\n'; // >>>>> The address still did not change after deletion
    arr[3] = nullptr;

    // ----- Release memory -----
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        delete arr[i];

    delete[] arr;
    // --------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x2ea1c30: 2
0x2ea1c30

0x2ea5f40 / 0x2ea5f40 : 3
0x2ea5f40 / 0x2ea5f40
```

As you can see, the pointer value did not change.

---

I think it is important to notice that you should set your deleted pointers to `nullptr` since they are still in your `Card` list even after the deletion.

Comment: Unfortunately I just figured out my issue. You can see the comments on my question for what happened. Should I accept your answer, respond with my solution, or simply delete my question?

Comment: @multitaskPro Ah right. It seems I took too much time to write my answer :) Feel free to do what you consider fair, upvote, downvote, accept or not, remove or not, or nothing at all :)